# Counter and call duration combination in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

```
int score = 0;
score += 1;
```

I wish to add 1 (`+= 1`) to `score` when call duration reach 30 seconds just once and reset the score to 0 when call duration is less than 30 seconds.

```
Text('$score')
```

and show it like this

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:call_log/call_log.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';
```

I have imported 3 packages above

```
void callLogs() async {
  Iterable<CallLogEntry> entries = await CallLog.get();
  for (var item in entries) {
    print(Duration());   <--- Use Duration & if statement to solve but duration not printing
   }
 }
```

and code I wrote above is not working as I imagined to even start with. What changes can I make for adding and resetting `score` to work? Please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code waits for this call to complete so it never runs anything under it:

```
Iterable<CallLogEntry> entries = await CallLog.get();
```

You could use the StopWatch object to get the time:

```
void callLogs() async {

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();

    Iterable<CallLogEntry> entries = await CallLog.get();
    for (var item in entries) {
        var duration = stopwatch.elapsed;
        print('Duration $duration');
   }
 }
```

And use setState() to set score:

```
setState(() { duration > 30 ? score += 1 : score = 0 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate it yet I'm still getting 2 major errors. First one is 'await expression can only be used in a async function.' and the other one is 'Undefined name 'duration.''. I'm working on to find a way to define duration and any additional help would be great.

Comment: You can only use the 'await' expression if your function is asyncronous like this one :

`void callLogs() async {}`

For the duration you could declare it locally or globally if you would need it somewhere else in your application.

Comment: What do you mean by locally or globally? Could you give me an example? Again, thank you

Comment: Globally would mean you would declare it in your class so all of your methods from that class would have access to it, and locally would be directly in the function your using it in so the variable only lives inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

if you variable score is inside of a widget or in the build method then i think that it set it to the begin value any time you run setState because setState builds the build again and also the widgets that is inside the build.

if that is so then try to make the variable global.

PS: global means that you the variable is outside of your class.

Comment: I created variables.dart to take the code outside the class and make it global. Unfortunately, nothing has changed so far. Will adding '.inSeconds' after one of 'duration' make any changes? Because I'm not sure if the system understand that duration > 5 is in second not minutes or hours.

Comment: I don't know -- sorry

Comment: It's all good. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it